# Como somar valores de uma matriz na diagonal da direita para esquerda com python?

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

Estou com uma atividade cujo o objetivo é exibir a diferença entre a soma das diagonais de uma matriz, com o numpy.trace só consegui fazer a soma da diagonal esquerda-direita, tem alguma maneira de com o próprio trace conseguir fazer a diagonal direita-esquerda?

meu código está atualmente assim:

```
import numpy 

def DifDiagonal(arr):
    return numpy.trace(arr,offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=1,dtype=None)

print(DifDiagonal([[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação
[`nympy.diagonals`](https://nympy.diagonals) a antidiagonal de uma matriz quadrada pode ser obtida invertendo a ordem dos elementos usando [`numpy.fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) que inverta a ordem dos elementos de uma matriz 2D ao longo do eixo 1 (esquerda/direita).

```
import numpy as np

def DifDiagonal(arr):
    return np.fliplr(arr).trace()
    
print(DifDiagonal([
  [11,  2,   4], 
  [ 4,  5,   6], 
  [10,  8, -12]]))
#19
```

Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Antidiagonal#main.py)

No exemplo acima são somados a diagonal cujo os elementos são `[4, 5, 10]` resultando em `19`.

Answer (score -1):

Basta inverter a matriz e calcular a mesma diagonal.

```
return numpy.trace(arr[::-1],offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=1,dtype=None)
```